# how to change directory in Jupyter Notebook with Special characters?

Tags: python-3.x

When I created directory under the python env, it has single quote like (D:\'Test Directory'). How do I change to this directory in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I could able to change the directory using escape sequence like this..

os.chdir('C:\\\'Test Directory\')

Answer (score 0):

I could able to change the directory using escape sequence like this.. os.chdir('C:\\'Test Directory\')